# How to define FOR loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, coinbase-api, termux

Please I need help here. In the code below, I want the FOR loop to loop through all the accounts with the associated API KEYs and SECRETs listed and send bitcoins from them to the recipient email address one after the other as long as their balance is greater than zero:

```
    #!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3.8

from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
import json

api_key1 = '<key>'
api_secret1 = '<secret>'
api_key2 = '<key>'
api_secret2 = '<secret>'
api_key3 = '<key>'
api_secret3 = '<secret>'
api_key4 = '<key>'
api_secret4 = '<secret>'
api_key5 = '<key>'
api_secret5 = '<secret>'
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
accounts = client.get_accounts()['data']
for account in accounts:
    sending_currency = account['currency']
    if float(account['balance']['amount']) > 0:
        #Send to other account
        sending_account = client.get_account(account['id'])
        sending_amount = account['balance']['amount']
        print('sending %s %s from SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS' %(sending_amount, sending_currency))
        sending_account.send_money(to = 'RECEPIENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS', amount = sending_amount, currency = sending_currency)
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? What does not work?

Comment: It works perfectly for single account. But I want to modify the script to loop through the 5 accounts whose API and SECRET are specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to attain what you have described, I would use a list of dictionaries, this will also be iterable and hence usable in the for loop. in order to do this I'd rewrite your code as such :

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3.8

from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
import json
credentials = [
{'api_key':'<key1>', 'api_secret':'<secret1>'},
{'api_key':'<key2>', 'api_secret':'<secret2>'},
{'api_key':'<key3>', 'api_secret':'<secret3>'}
........
]
while True:
    for credential in credentials:
        client = Client(credential['api_key'], credential['api_secret'])
        accounts = client.get_accounts()['data']
        for account in accounts:
            sending_currency = account['currency']
            if float(account['balance']['amount']) > 0:
                 #Send to other account
                 sending_account = client.get_account(account['id'])
                 sending_amount = account['balance']['amount']
                 print('sending %s %s from SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS' %(sending_amount, sending_currency))
                 sending_account.send_money(to = 'RECEPIENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS', amount = sending_amount, currency = sending_currency)
            else:
                ........
```

Comment: P.S. I'm interested in the Project. Drop the link and I'll help you out. I can see where this is going. XD

Comment: I ran your code and here is what I got `python
Python 3.8.0 (default, Dec  5 2019, 10:53:43)
[Clang 8.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang b55f2d4ebfd35bf6 on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/test2.py", line 6
    {api_key = '<key1>', api_secret = '<secret1>'},
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>`

Comment: The syntax error was seen on line 6 of that code probably at the `credentials = [...]` line

Comment: Yes I mistyped a quote, try running the program now

Comment: It's saying the same thing

Comment: I tried replacing this `[...]`` with this `"..."` and put the API keys and secrets all in one line and it didn't complain of invalid syntax again but now it is saying `TypeError: string indexes must be integer`

Comment: My bad again I'm just distracted sorry.

Comment: Have you made any change?

Comment: Yes the code will work now, just keep in mind to remove the "........."

Comment: It works!!! You are genius! But how can I make the code run forever like a loop. And never stops

Comment: It will run as long as you have credentials, repeating the same credentials doesn't make sense for a bruteforce program

Comment: I learnt that iterating over a list is always terminated once the iteration gets to the last list in a FOR loop. I want something like a WHILE loop that once the script is executed it keeps iterating over the lists and when it gets to the end it starts afresh again. I need it to run forever once executed once until the device goes off

Comment: Ok it works but with nothing printed on the screen, so I guess it is working the background now, no indication to know its working. Is there a way to add `else` block? So that if the balance is `0` it will run else block

Comment: Umm Yes? Just add the else block?

Comment: Where will add it? I am familiar with bash. Python is still new to me I am yet to know it properly. The indentation rule in python is still confusing to me

Comment: This isn't a question for StackOverflow but yeah I did help you, accept it as the answer if it's correct.

Comment: I have accepted it as answer. Thanks a million times